# Xubuntu becomes very laggy after hours

Tags: gnome, graphics, xubuntu, 16.04, cpu

When I start my laptop, there is no problems : no lag, it's not superfluid but it's OK.

After few hours (~4/5 hours) Ubuntu and Gnome suddenly become very very slow : 3 or 4 seconds of delay when I press Super Key, letters appears 2 ou 3 seconds after I've released the key... If I restart the PC it's OK. I have to restart it 4 times a day to be able to work...

Configuration :

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz
```

Sensors :

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit = +125.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
```

Graphics card :

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

There's no swap since I disabled it, without success. It's not SWAP (8 GB of RAM).

A screenshot of htop, with CPU & memory usage :

[image]

Running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with LightDM and Gnome Shell. It's a Toshiba Satellite C855-1JN

Any ideas ?

Thanks !